# RSS read in MVC view

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, rss

I want to load RSS data into a view but don't know where to start.
below in a sample feed URl:
http://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/topstories.xml

how can I use the url above and show news in a view?

Answer (score 0):

There are some classes built-in the .NET Framework to read and produce RSS feeds (look under the System.ServiceModel.Syndication namespace.

This is a good article on the subject:

http://www.dotnetbips.com/articles/addaf09f-9b6b-45d2-aba8-da11f23aa53e.aspx

**Update:** I assumed you are using ASP.NET MVC but then I realized you don't indicate what MVC framework are you using. Hope it was ASP.NET MVC otherwise my answer would be useless.